# Drupal Login Form Disabled apparently. How to login? Standard login urls don't work. Anyway to enable from the database?

Tags: php, drupal

wanted to seek help regarding the login form not showing up even after trying to access these urls:

> mysite.url/user/login 
>   mysite.url/?q=user/login
>   mysitename.url/user

any way i can enable it from the database?

only shows me a page with the header and this link "Set or reset a forgotten password" which, when clicked won't really show anything.

Drupal v7.34

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you change the theme? (Maybe something in the new theme is preventing the login page from showing correctly).

Comment: Search some hook who altering path and disable modifications to get classical login

Comment: Thanks, guys. i'll check. I've just took over this, that's why. really don't have any history as well, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try setup drush and then try the following command to login into the site.

```
drush user-login OR drush uli
```

https://drushcommands.com/drush-7x/user/user-login/

Comment: thanks. i was able to run drush, however, it was pointing out to a different issue. not sure if it's connected but i've added it on queue as wlel.

Comment: Can you specify the error you are seeing after drush command?